# Deploy Database dacpac with Powershell: Exception calling "Deploy" with "3" argument(s): "Could not deploy package."

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016, powershell-ise, dacpac

I am trying to deploy a database dacpac with powershell and receiving error below. Anyone know how to fix this? I am thinking its due to me having SQL Server 2016. Trying to understand what the error message means.
Here is the code: Main error seems unable to connect to localhost?? This basic user access. I tried right clicking and Running As Administrator on Powershell, still does not work.

```
add-type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"

$dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices "server=localhost"

$dp = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage]::Load("C:\Test\ScaffoldTest.dacpac")

try
{
    $dacService.deploy($dp, "ScaffoldTest", "True") 
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "LoadException";
    $Error | format-list -force
    Write-Host $Error[0].Exception.ParentContainsErrorRecordException;
}
```

**Error:**

```
    Exception calling "Deploy" with "3" argument(s): "Could not deploy package."
    At line:32 char:1
    + $dacService.deploy($dp, "ScaffoldTest", "True")
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DacServicesException





Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Deploy" with "3" argument(s): "Could not deploy package." ---> 
                        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: Could not deploy package. ---> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentFailedException: Unable to connect 
                        to target server 'localhost'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server. ---> 
                        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
                           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, 
                        Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData 
                        reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
                           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, 
                        DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions 
                        userOptions)
                           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, 
                        DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                           at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
                        TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                           at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.<OpenConnection>b__0()
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ExecuteAction>b__3(RetryState retryState)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[R](Func`2 func, Nullable`1 token)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action`1 action, Nullable`1 token)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action action, Nullable`1 token)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.OpenConnection()
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableConnectionHelper.OpenConnection(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Boolean useRetry)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableConnectionHelper.OpenConnection(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Action`1 usingConnection, 
                        Predicate`1 catchException, Boolean useRetry)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableConnectionHelper.GetServerAndDatabaseVersion(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, 
                        ServerAndDatabaseInfo& info)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlDatabaseSchemaProviderFamily.DetermineSqlPlatform(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, CompatibilityLevelVerification 
                        verificationMode, String& errorMessage)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlDatabaseSchemaProviderFamily.DetermineDatabaseSchemaProvider(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String& errorMessage)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlDatabaseSchemaProviderFamily.DetermineDatabaseSchemaProvider(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.GetProviderType(DatabaseSchemaProviderFamily connectionSniffer, SqlConnectionFactory 
                        connectionFactory, Type& providerType, Boolean& validDataSource, SqlException& exception)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.OnInit(ErrorManager errors, String targetDBName)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment..ctor(SqlDeploymentConstructor constructor)
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentConstructor.ConstructServiceImplementation()
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreatePackageToDatabaseDeployment(SqlConnectionFactory connectionFactory, IPackageSource packageSource, String 
                        targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, ErrorManager errorManager)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
                           at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, 
                        CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)
                           at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 
                        cancellationToken)
                           at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , String , String )
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
```

Comment: Well it says `Login failed for user ''`, so maybe check the SQL Server error logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SQL Server is using Windows Authentication you need to indicate that in your connection string:

```bsh
$dacService = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices "server=localhost;Integrated Security=True;"
```